# Unity android oneSignal error on tagged push notification

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am able to send push notifications from oneSignal web panel, but not throught my APP.
The error is

> Segment or tag targeting requires a valid App REST API Key.

Ok, I have my REST API key but I can`t find in the whole documentation what to do with it... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Specific Devices Usage](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-specific-devices-usage) on create notification method:

> This method requires an application `REST API Key` when using `include_segments` or `filters`, which is available in [Keys & IDs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids).
>
> **NEVER** use your `REST API key` in client code, it is intended for use on your system or server only. Add the REST API Key to the HTTP 'Authorization' header as basic authentication.

You may want to also check discussion in [Keys & IDs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids) for instructions on the use of your key. As also mentioned,

> To use your key, add an HTTP header with the key `Authorization` and the value `Basic REST_API_KEY`, where you should replace `REST_API_KEY` with your actual `APP REST API key`.
>
> [image]
>
> The keys for all your apps are also available all together within the Account section.

Hope that helps!